# commands auto capitalization in andriod studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, settings

I want to change my android studio setting in a way that when I write:
system.out.print();
it automatically change it to caps: System.out.print();
with out the need to turn on capslock every time

Comment: is shift + S really that much work ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In intelliJ there is a setting called `Postfix Completion` where you could configure that. I think it might exist in android studio as well. By default shortcut is "sout"

Answer (score 1):

you can simply write "sout" then press Tab you will get "System.out.print("");" written immediately